# MySQL Error Code 1054- inserting data is unsucessful

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I need help with a MySQL program, this is the code:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Customerid, CustomerFname, CustomerLname, CustomerPhone, CustomerGender, CustomerYearly_salary, CustomerStreet, CustomerCity, CustomerState, CustomerPostcode, ProductId, PaymentId)

VALUES (12345678910,’Anna’, ’English’, 017362930115, ‘female’, 30000, ‘Augsburger_Str._84‘, ‘Senscheid’, ‘Rheinland-Pfalz’, 53520, 0101, 50000)
```

This is the error code:

> INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Customerid, CustomerFname, CustomerLname, CustomerPhone, CustomerGender, CustomerYearly_salary, CustomerStreet, CustomerCity, CustomerState, CustomerPostcode, ProductId, PaymentId)
> >VALUES (12345678910,’Anna’, ’English’, 017362930115, ‘female’, 30000, ‘Augsburger_Str._84‘, ‘Senscheid’, ‘Rheinland-Pfalz’, 53520, 0101, 50000)

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '’Anna’' in 'field list'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: I think you're using backticks for the string values? Backticks are used for referencing database objects.

Comment: It looks like you're using smart-quote characters, not ASCII single-quote characters, for the string literal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQL thinks that Anna (and other values in front) are Columns as per the error message, replace with quotation marks:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Customerid, CustomerFname, CustomerLname, CustomerPhone, CustomerGender, CustomerYearly_salary, CustomerStreet, CustomerCity, CustomerState, CustomerPostcode, ProductId, PaymentId);

VALUES (12345678910, 'Anna', 'English', 017362930115, 'female', 30000, 'Augsburger_Str._84', 'Senscheid', 'Rheinland-Pfalz', 53520, 0101, 50000);
```

Comment: Add semi-colons to the end of the lines.